# Internal Error in Redmine Initialization phase

Tags: redmine

I'm trying to setup Redmine on the following products

```
redmine-4.0.7
Rails 5.2.4.2
Phusion Passenger 6.0.7
Apache/2.4.6
mysql  Ver 14.14
```

I expected there will be initializing page however, I got `Internal Error' from http://mydomain/redmine/

I can see the following messages in log/prduction.log

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 21ms (ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Can't find file: './redmine/settings.frm' (errno: 13 - Permission denied): SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `settings`):
```

It seems I need `./redmine/settings.frm` but there isn't.

Does anyone know how to place `./redmine/settings.frm` and what content should be in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is thrown by your database server (i.e. MySQL). It seems that MySQL does not have the required permission to access the files where it stores the table data.

Usually, those files are handled (i.e. created, updated, and eventually deleted) entirely by MySQL which requires specific access patterns to ensure consistent data. Because of that, you should strongly avoid to manually change any files under control of MySQL. Instead, you should only use SQL commands to update table structures and table data.

o fix this issue now, you need to fix the permissions of your MySQL data files so that MySQL can properly access them. What exactly is required here is unfortunately not simply explained since there can be various causes. If you have jsut setup your MySQL server, it might be best start entirely new.

Comment: thank you.the permission wasn't right as you pointed.